# Como esconder uma string em C, para que ela não esteja legível no código compilado?

Tags: c, string

Tenho uma string `Hello World`, mas não quero guarda-la como `Hello World` no C, gostaria de guardá-la como algum valor em base64, aes ou binário, ou similar, de modo que ela não ficasse legível no código.

Como eu poderia guardar essa string, e retornar o seu valor em um `print` por exemplo?

Comment: Vc quer uma forma de representar números binários (base 2) através de algum tipo de dados especifico para ele?

Comment: Não sei se existe binário literal em C, talvez deva existir algo q simule isso.

Comment: Na verdade poderia ser algo em base64 também.

Comment: Achei [esta biblioteca](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#BOOST_BINARY) que permite trabalhar com números de base 2.

Comment: Reformule a pergunta também, deixe mais especifica sua necessidade.

Comment: Pergunta reformulada, espero ter deixado mais claro o que estou tentando fazer, obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Nada mais perigoso que a falsa sensação de segurança!

Comment: https://gist.github.com/barrysteyn/7308212

Comment: Gosto do perigo, e não são dados importantes :)

Comment: Provavelmente você vai precisar usar um algoritmo de criptografia

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Definitivamente essa não é uma boa prática. Se trata de uma falsa sensação de segurança acreditar que ninguém será capaz de ler um dado só porque ele foi armazenado usando uma representação diferente.

Todavia, segue um código (testado) capaz de decodificar uma string em base64:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


static const unsigned char pr2six[256] =
{
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 62, 64, 64, 64, 63,
    52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
    15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40,
    41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64
};


int Base64decode( char * bufplain, const char * bufcoded )
{
    int nbytesdecoded;
    register const unsigned char *bufin;
    register unsigned char *bufout;
    register int nprbytes;

    bufin = (const unsigned char *) bufcoded;
    while (pr2six[*(bufin++)] <= 63);
    nprbytes = (bufin - (const unsigned char *) bufcoded) - 1;
    nbytesdecoded = ((nprbytes + 3) / 4) * 3;

    bufout = (unsigned char *) bufplain;
    bufin = (const unsigned char *) bufcoded;

    while (nprbytes > 4)
    {
        *(bufout++) = (unsigned char) (pr2six[*bufin] << 2 | pr2six[bufin[1]] >> 4);
        *(bufout++) = (unsigned char) (pr2six[bufin[1]] << 4 | pr2six[bufin[2]] >> 2);
        *(bufout++) = (unsigned char) (pr2six[bufin[2]] << 6 | pr2six[bufin[3]]);
        bufin += 4;
        nprbytes -= 4;
    }

    if (nprbytes > 1)
    {
        *(bufout++) = (unsigned char) (pr2six[*bufin] << 2 | pr2six[bufin[1]] >> 4);
    }

    if (nprbytes > 2)
    {
        *(bufout++) = (unsigned char) (pr2six[bufin[1]] << 4 | pr2six[bufin[2]] >> 2);
    }

    if (nprbytes > 3)
    {
        *(bufout++) = (unsigned char) (pr2six[bufin[2]] << 6 | pr2six[bufin[3]]);
    }

    *(bufout++) = '\0';
    nbytesdecoded -= (4 - nprbytes) & 3;

    return nbytesdecoded;
}


int main( void )
{
    char * encoded = "SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh";
    char decoded[ 100 ] = {0};

    Base64decode( decoded, encoded );

    printf("String codificada  : %s\n", encoded );
    printf("String decodificada: %s\n", decoded );

    return 0;
}

/* fim-de-arquivo */
```

Compilando (gcc/linux):

```
$ gcc base64.c -o base64
```

Saída:

```
$ ./base64 
String codificada  : SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh
String decodificada: Hello World!
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 4):

Para "esconder" a string podes aplicar o [rot13](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13)

```
#include <string.h> // para strchr()

// aplica rot13 a src e mete o resultado em dst
// se dst nao tiver tamanho suficiente invoca UB
// devolve dst
char *rot13(const char *src, char *dst) {
    static char alpha[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm"
                          "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM";
    char *bak = dst;
    char *pa;
    while (*src) {
        if ((pa = strchr(alpha, *src)) != NULL) {
            *dst = pa[13];
        } else {
            *dst = *src;
        }
        dst++;
        src++;
    }
    *dst = 0;
    return bak;
}
```

Podes aplicar esta função no teu programa, por exemplo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "rot13.h"

int main(void) {
    char x[] = "Uryyb, Jbeyq!";
    printf("rot13: %s\n", rot13(x, x));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muito interessante, já tinha visto matérias de criptografias com temas semelhantes, obrigado por compartilhar.